# hyperref + cleveref: Turn cross reference color to blue

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I currently use `cleveref` for cross-reference. I was wondering how to turn cross-reference to blue color ? An example would be as follows :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue,linkcolor=Blue, citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}

\crefname{section}{\textbf{Section}}{\textbf{Sections}}

\begin{document}
    \section{A theorem}\label{section:1}
    \cref{section:1} is useful to prove theorem b. 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Sorry, I am about to leave my apartment.
- I just provide some code (no time for more).
- Is the result what you want?

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks = true,
    linkcolor = blue
    }
    
\usepackage[
        noabbrev,
        capitalise,
        nameinlink,
    ]
    {cleveref}

\begin{document}
    \section{A theorem}\label{section:1}
    \cref{section:1} is useful to prove theorem b. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes I think so ! Also, if there is any way to only turn number(1) to blue ?

Comment: @exteral Try removing `nameinlink` and read the manual! :)